# How to plot a network without background connection or labels? R pegas

Tags: r, plot

I have made a haplotype network using the pegas package following the instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755930/how-to-plot-pie-charts-in-haplonet-haplotype-networks-pegas). It has successfully plotted but as you can see from the following figure, all the connection labels are ploted giving the graph a crowded appearance. How can I remove these.

```
plot(net, size = attr(net, "freq"), pie=ind.hap, fast = TRUE, legend=F, label=NULL, vertices.last=F)
legend('topleft', capitalize(colnames(ind.hap)), col=rainbow(ncol(ind.hap)), pch=20, cex=0.7)
```

[image: Plotted network]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can adjust that by setting `threshold = 0` in your `plot()` call, that is:

```
plot(net, size = attr(net, "freq"), pie=ind.hap, fast = TRUE, legend=F, label=NULL, threshold = 0)
```

See help for `?pegas::plot.haploNet` for more details. Also please note that the post you mention ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755930/how-to-plot-pie-charts-in-haplonet-haplotype-networks-pegas?rq=1)) has a bug where the pie-chart is being coloured wrongly (I've made a comment about it and also posted a corrected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220586/r-how-to-plot-correct-pie-charts-in-haplonet-haplotyp-networks-pegas-ape-a/33107267#33107267)).

Comment: I've did get to see the second answer to the question and in fact i linked incorrectly to the first one; thank you for noting. I've marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
plot(net, size = attr(net, "freq"), pie=ind.hap, fast = TRUE, legend=F, label=NULL, vertices.last=F), col=rainbow(ncol(ind.hap)), pch=20, cex=0.7)
```

That is your code without the legend('topleft', capitalize(colnames....) argument.

Does that work?

Comment: The `legend(...)` function is in a separate line. The network is  independent of the legend. I will how ever remove the `vertices.last` argument as it does produce a warning, and has no noticeble effect on the graph.